# Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be twice differentiable and assume $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. Show that $f(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable and assume $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f"(x)<0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. Show that $f(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$.

I'm not entirely sure where to start for this problem. I'm confused on how the second derivative can help to show the first is positive?

Comment: Hm, the claim should certainly be merely that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the MWT:
Assume $f(x)\le 0$ for some $x\in(a,b)$. Then for some $\xi\in(a,x)$ we have $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\le 0$ and for some $\eta\in(x,b)$ we have $f'(\eta)=\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}\ge 0$. Then for some $\theta\in(\xi,\eta)$ we have $f''(\theta)=\frac{f'(\eta)-f'(\xi)}{\eta-\xi}>0$, contradiction! Therefore $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.